# MongoDB associative array - pull possible?

Tags: mongodb, pull

Having the following Array:

```
array(
      'id' => 12,
      'keys' => array('x1' => array('idx' => 12, 'text'=> '1123145'),
                      'x2' => array('idx' => 14, 'text'=> '1123142'),
                      'x3' => array('idx' => 12, 'text'=> '1123145'),
                      'x4' => array('idx' => 14, 'text'=> '1123145')
                      )
     )
```

I want to pull all keys with idx 12. So i do the following:

```
$mdb->db->collection->update(array('id' => 12), array('$pull' => array('keys' => array('idx' => 12))));
```

But it don't works, whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to do with this schema.
you are trying to pull the id = 12 from the array key, but the problem, is that each element of key is an object by itself.

the only way to do what you want with minimum modification is change schema in this way:

```
{
  "_id" : 12,
  "keys" : [
      {
        "type" : 'x1',
        "idx" : 12,
        "text" : "1111"
      },
      {
        "type" : 'x2',
        "idx" : 14,
        "text" : "1111"
      },
      {
        "type" : 'x3',
        "idx" : 12,
        "text" : "1111"
      },
      {
        "type" : 'x4',
        "idx" : 14,
        "text" : "1111"
      }
    }]
}
```

than you can run your query as follows:

```
db.XXX.update(
{ "_id" : 12},
{
  '$pull' : {
     'keys' : {
    'idx' : 12
     }
  }
}
);
```

I hope you will be able to transfer this into php with an arrays, because it looks for me that you are using php for querying

Comment: there is a way with "$" operator also. But I have no time to represent it now.